# I can't open browser with WatiN in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, automation, clicking

I'm programming a basic script using C#. I want to make an script what open Internet Explorer (or any other browser) and clicking, but, always have the same error, even when use FireFox: It never recognizes the URL

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using WatiN.Core;


namespace testConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                IE ie = new IE("https://www.google.com");
                ie.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).Value = "Youtube KeyEventHandler";
                ie.NativeDocument.Body.SetFocus();
                ie.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();

                Console.WriteLine(ie.Div(Find.ById("resultStats")).Text);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know much about that package, but it's pretty old. I did attempt to use it in a few different framework versions, and I did get the error you're getting - among others. I doubt this package is even maintained any more?

Comment: The last time the Nuget package was updated was 12 years ago, in 2011.

Comment: You can use `Process.Start` to start the user's preferred browser. But if you want access to the DOM, use Windows Forms and a browser control and _Navigate_ to your desired URL

Comment: Looking at your exception (if you had included it in text, I would have noticed it), it looks like that `IE` type expects to be in a Windows Forms app. Yours is a console app

Comment: Thank you very much for your precision. I am new to C#. The easiest way to get C# to open the browser and click on an element is with Windows Forms?

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement you should use Winforms to open a browser and jump to the target website:

1. Create a Windows Forms App (.Net Framework)

[image]

2. Drag a button and double-click the button

[image]

[image]

3. Refer to the following code:

   ```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string explorpath = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"; // Browser path, directly enter "explorer.exe" as the default browser

        string site = "https://test"; //destination site url

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(explorpath, site);
    }
   ```

After running, click the button to use a specific browser to visit a specific website